# Add custom data into Nominatim geocoding search?

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

I have installed Nominatim on my local server to receive addresses from long/lat. I would like to add custom data to the search itself. I would like to store locations of the rooms of our buildings.  Is this possible?

---

We are storing polygon data for different types (layers) of objects. How can those be returned by Nominatim?
E.x.:
 - return data from layer: water_protection_areas
 - return room polygons for specific address for 4th floor
 - return room id(s) for specific geocode

(by Mihail-Klr, we are researching on this topic, if we should find a solution, I'll post it)